# How can one retract or undo a flag on a post?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

OK,
  to give an example - [How does one customize Kubuntu Search and Launch (with the Plasma-Netbook interface)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57169/how-does-one-customize-kubuntu-search-and-launch-with-the-plasma-netbook-interfa/58846#58846)

When the user posted the answer it clearly wasnt an answer - in this case it was just a bunch of questions as you can see by the edit.

So I flagged the answer.  Sometime later the poster changed his answer to what looks like a valid answer.

So my question is - being a good citizen (!) - I flagged the answer correctly, but no moderators were around to deal with this flagging.  When they are, they'll reject my flagging seeing only the now correctly editing answer - thus "penalizing" my flagging reputation.

There doesnt appear anyway to "undo" my flagging - or is there?

Answer (score 11):

Following [this longstanding request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/203389) you can now retract flags you have cast.  Simply click the "flag" button again on the post you flagged and the "Flag Answer" (or "Flag Question") button becomes "Retract Flag".  This does not work on comments.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer as this was recently implemented.

Comment: I was just about to post a meta question about this exact thing. But then I found this. Good to know that I'm not going crazy; it was a recent thing :)