# How do I cancel a flag request?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to undo a flagging](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1746/how-to-undo-a-flagging)

I don't see a way to cancel a "flag for moderation" request once I've made it, if I see that it was in error.

Is there a way to do it? If not, should there be?

Comment: Questions like this make me wish I could upvote more than once. Few things are more aggravating than flagging a question, having somebody else edit it to make it more acceptable, then being penalized for the flagging because it doesn't fit the new version.

Comment: If it is at all likely that a question could be improved so as not to deserve flagging, wouldn't it ordinarily deserve a downvote and explanatory comment, but not a flag, in the first place? If what a post needs is something *other* than moderator attention and/or deletion, why is it inappropriate to be penalized for flagging it?

Comment: @EliahKagan Examples might include [very low quality posts](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1948/18612). Occasionally, a post might come along that looks flaggable at first glance, but you then have second thoughts about it after the fact. It is entirely possible to flag something by mistake and wish you could take it back later.

Comment: Here's [another example](http://askubuntu.com/posts/97725/revisions) I just ran into. The original answer was a "me too" response, but after flagging it the user deleted it, undeleted it, and edited it back into an acceptable answer. The content of the answer changed so radically there was no way edits by someone else could have improved it without changing what the answer basically said.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1746/18612

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to cancel a flag once cast. I haven't ever seen this request come up before, so I am not sure this is enough of an actual problem to warrant action.

Comment: What about situations then where the person who posted had a question/answer which clearly did not belong according to the FAQ, then after flagging it they completely rewrote their own post to become acceptable? IMO edits by others could not achieve this without fundamentally changing the content of the post. See my above comment for an example where this actually happened.