# How can I take back my request for moderator attention

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one retract or undo a flag on a post?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1746/how-can-one-retract-or-undo-a-flag-on-a-post)

I had used the `it needs ♦ moderator attention` flagging option asking for moderator to close this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101030/apache-virtualhost-keeps-pointing-to-default-directory), as I has asked it in past (when I was using Ubuntu 11.10), but now don't know the exact answer. But after some time I found that the posted answer is actually correct, as that is the setup I use in my current Ubuntu version(12.04) which works fine. So, how can I take back my request for moderator attention, or ask them not to delete that question?